# Pulling an Array from API (Twitch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitch

I am in no way a coder, all I know how to do is manipulate a bit of code to work, I managed to pull a Live Follower and Views from Twitch's API, but I am having trouble with this code that pulls the Live Viewers... It doesn't seem to want to work. I don't know how to look in Googles' Inspect Element to see what's wrong, and I don't know how to fix it. Do you see anything wrong with this code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.views').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + tnick + '.json?callback=?', function (data) {
            var views = data.viewers;
            span.html(views);

        });
    });
});
```

And the HTML

```
<p><i data-tnick="GamerGirlsNetwork" class="fa fa-eye views"></i>  <span>0</span>
```

I have multiple users on the site, so I need it to take the parameters from the HTML, but even without the Parameters from HTML and having it in the Code, it still won't call the data.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXUVIAX/7dgx971v/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not the same as the code you show us here :-/ It works for me. I don't get the data you want but the call is made.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the query when the stream is online. If the stream is not online, the `stream` key will always be `null`.

Here is something that should work

```
    $('.views').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + tnick + '.json?callback=?', function (data) {
            if(data.stream === null){
               span.html('0 viewers because stream is offline !'); // Stream is offline
            }
            else{ // stream is online !
               var views = data.viewers;
               span.html(views);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Channels doesn't show the live viewers, only Streams does.

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear that :-( I'm no pro of twitch api. Maybe you have to make the call when the stream is online ?

Comment: I suggest that you make some test with a twitch stream that is online and compare the result you get with a twitch stream that is offline.